# How to divide a number into multiple columns or rows in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need help to divide a number into multiple columns or rows.

For example A1 has 32000. I need to divide it by 10000. So the data will divide into multiple columns or rows, but the residual value is still written.

So `A1 = 32000`

```
B1 = 10000
B2 = 10000
B3 = 10000
B4 = 2000
```

The divider can change and the result does not always in 4 columns or rows.

Sorry for my bad English & Grammar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this formula: `=IF(($A$1-SUM($B$1:B1))>B1,B1,$A$1-SUM($B$1:B1))`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks you mr lee, that's what exactly i wanted to do with my excel

Comment: Lee you deserve perfect 10. :-)